# Getting error while getting data from db and using mapping (orika) - ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, mapper, orika

**ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: Encountered mapping of enum to object (or vise-versa)**

> ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: Encountered mapping of enum to object (or vise-versa); sourceType=AccountPlan, destinationType=Plan
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.specification.UnmappableEnum.generateMappingCode(UnmappableEnum.java:41) ~[orika-core-1.5.0.jar:na]
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.SourceCodeContext.mapFields(SourceCodeContext.java:778) ~[orika-core-1.5.0.jar:na]

```
           return accountRepository.findById(id)
               .map(account -> mapper.map(account, AccountDetail.class))
               .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFound("Account not found Id: " + id));
```

Comment: UnmappableEnum is a place-holder specification to catch types which cannot be mapped. As far as I understand AccountPlan field is expected but your entity contains Plan field

Comment: Add Orika's mapping config to your Question

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback, after adding Account Plan mappers it is working @alexvaluiskyi